# Match sentence inside bracket if exists

Tags: regex

With this input:

```
foo XYZ
to-ignore(bar XYZ)
```

I need to match:

```
foo XYZ
bar XYZ
```

This pattern:
`(.*? XYZ)`

is giving me unwanted `to-ignore(` part.

I also managed something like this:
`[^|\(](.*? XYZ)`

I expected `[^|\(]` to select beginning of a string or bracket, but its not working. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you match `var` when it doesn't exist in your string?

Comment: Maybe you want `\w+ XYZ`?

Comment: @ctwheels I edited the code

Comment: @ctwheels there can be more words

Comment: OK, what about `[\w\s-]+ XYZ`

Comment: `[` introduces a character class, not a group. `[^|\(]` means "a character that is not a `|` and not a `(`."

Answer (score 2):

in javascript:

```
'foo XYZ\nto-ignore(bar XYZ)'.match(/[^\(]+? XYZ/g)
```

the trick is not to include the opening bracket into match

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work in Java.

```java
      String regex = "(.*)?(foo|bar) XYZ\\)?";
      System.out.println("foo XYZ".matches(regex));
      System.out.println("to-ignore(bar XYZ)".matches(regex));
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work : `((^[^(]+ )|(?<=\().* )XYZ`

However : you have to use the multiline flag `m` and it uses a positive lookahead which isn't universally supported

[Here's what it looks like](https://regexr.com/4qj39) on regexr.com with some examples

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, it uses (?!) to ignore every thing before bracket including the bracket itself, and (.+?) to select every thing before XYZ:

```
/(?!.*\()(.+?)XYZ/g
```

Comment: While providing an answer is great, try to avoid code-only answers and add some additional description of the solution.

Comment: Thank you for your notice, I've edited the answer :)

Comment: @HebaFareed its actually grabing `(bar XYZ` https://regex101.com/r/ZrkMmN/1

Comment: Try this update: https://regex101.com/r/ZrkMmN/3 (?!.*\()(.+?)XYZ